# SSH connection between 2 Ubuntu VMs with ObenNebula

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, virtual-machine

I need to connect to Ubuntu 12.04 VMs via SSH, but it doesn't seem to work. I've gone through all the steps that seem to be OK for setting it up.
First, I installed one Ubuntu VM, updated its repositories via *sudo apt-get update* and installed *sudo apt-get install opennebula*. Also, I changed the oneadmin password to a custom one. On the other VM that's supposed to be a node machine in my cloud system, I also updated repositories and installed *sudo apt-get install opennebula-node*, and changed the oneadmin password to a custom one. After doing that, I'm instructed to use the (from a homework assignment) xx.xx.56.xx IP address (the sample was *ssh oneadmin@192.168.56.102*) to connect to the front-end VM (the first one in this case, from the second one).
I was told that the IP address shown from the node VM (*ip addr*), *should* have this pattern with 56, but I never see one by using this command.

Any suggestions? Thanks. I've been trying to finish this for more than a week.

Comment: You did not say which hypervisor you are using

Comment: Oh yes, I'll be using KVM. But I still haven't got to that part. I'm using KVM to use OpenNebula, but VirtualBox for starting up Ubuntus.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure the Network Adapter s for the Ubuntu machines? You have several possibilities, the easiest of which is to use a *Bridge Adapter*.

Go to Network -> Adapter 1 -> Attached to , choose *Bridged Adapter*, and under Name, pick the host network interface currently operating. Now, when you start the VMs, they will be gin LAN IP addresses, just like the host, and connecting, if you have set up *ssh servers* on any of them, is just a matter of

```
   ssh my_name@my_Ubuntu_pc1's_IP_address
```

The 192.168.56.0/24 network you refer to above, is for the so-called *Hst only network*, which means each VM will be able to talk exclusively to the Host, not to each other. You may think you do not wish to have the VMs to be capable of talking to each other, but you still must configure different subnets for your two Ubuntu VMs, otherwise the host will not know how to talk to one or to the other.